# NotificationListener not working on Android

Tags: flutter

NotificationListener is not seem to be working on Android - IOS works.

If you run the following program on a IOS device, you'll see the phrase 'hello world' output. Android does not invoke the callback function _onStartScroll() at all.

```
class TempScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: NotificationListener(
          onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
            if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
              _onStartScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
            }
          },
          child: CustomScrollView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("Swipe Down"),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  _onStartScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
      print('hello world');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, i am not sure why your code is not working but can you check [this closed issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39522) on github where it did not work on ios instead and maybe start another issue or attach logs there.

Comment: Have tried to run the above code in android? if so , did it work for you? IOS seems to work for me.

Comment: No it did not work, try the code in the answer below, UserScrollNotification is true on Android. I am not sure why the difference though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[[ScrollUpdateNotification]](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollUpdateNotification-class.html) indicate that the widget has changed its scroll position.

so if your widget has changed its scroll position,you will get [ScrollUpdateNotification]

but the IOS scrollView use [BouncingScrollPhysics] as default physics. It allow the scroll offset to go beyond the bounds of the content,so it will changed scroll position;

the android scrollView use [ClampingScrollPhysics] as default physics.If your content can't fill the scrollView,It does not allow change scroll positon. so you can't get [ScrollUpdateNotification]

so how to get [ScrollUpdateNotification] on Android devices?maybe you can changed CustomScrollView physics,like this:

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: NotificationListener(
          onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
            if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
              _onStartScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
            }
          },
          child: CustomScrollView(
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(parent: BouncingScrollPhysics()),
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("Swipe Down"),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  _onStartScroll(ScrollMetrics metrics) {
    print('hello world');
  }
}
```

change **AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()** to **const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(parent: BouncingScrollPhysics())**,then you will get [ScrollUpdateNotification] event.

If you don't want to change the physics，maybe you need use GestureDetector to get user touch event.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code above does not work on Android too but when i add a check if the scrollNotification is a UserScrollNotification it works.

E.g.

```dart
NotificationListener(
          onNotification: (scrollNotification) {
            if (scrollNotification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
              _onStartScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
            }else if (scrollNotification is UserScrollNotification ){
              _onStartScroll(scrollNotification.metrics);
            }

            return true;
          },
          child: CustomScrollView(
            physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            slivers: <Widget>[
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                child: Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text("Swipe Down"),
                  ),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ))
```

I don't have a Mac so i cant test it on IOS but i hope this helps. Let me know if the check for ScrollUpdateNotification is necessary when you run this in IOS.